# I can't find element to enter text with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to enter text into the email box but it seems like the find_element_by_name isn't working. Could anyone help me find out why it won't work? Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Brandon\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe") 
browser.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/@me')
time.sleep(10)

email = browser.find_element_by_name(email) 
email.send_keys('hi') 
email.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

[inspecting email chat box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfrSD.png)

Comment: email = browser.find_element_by_name(email)  what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the quotations because you're looking for a string, otherwise you're telling to look what email contains as a variable (which you haven't declared it yet and hence the error):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Brandon\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe") 
browser.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/@me')
time.sleep(10)

email = browser.find_element_by_name('email') 
email.send_keys('hi') 
email.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find element by xpath. it's type so try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
desktop = 'c:\\users\\' + username + '\\desktop\\'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=desktop +"chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://discordapp.com/channels/@me')
time.sleep(10)
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="email"]')
email.send_keys('hi')
email.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

i checked it works